# Trying to replicate `tezos-client sign bytes` command with javascript

Tags: tezos-client, tezos-signer

I'm trying to learn Tezos by creating a library (canibalizing eztz and sotes along the way :-) ) and I've hit a problem. I'm trying to replicate the signature from `tezos-client sign bytes` command in my library but it is not working.

The command I'm using is:

```
./babylonnet.sh client sign bytes 0x03ce69c5713dac3537254e7be59759cf59c15abd530d10501ccf9028a5786314cf08000002298c03ed7d454a101eb7022bc95f7e5f41ac78d0860303c8010080c2d72f0000e7670f32038107a59a2b9cfefae36ea21f5aa63c00 for roppa
```

And I get this result:

```
edsigthYSDK9c6BHkzrvYF2zWBoSMm56szAhZ8eAWuvv5QuRd8UqsaChX43Ch7iBE37wcyo1GmXzXoiUvE9BPStzysvytBfN6ed
```

When using eztz I get:

```
eztz.crypto.sign('ce69c5713dac3537254e7be59759cf59c15abd530d10501ccf9028a5786314cf08000002298c03ed7d454a101eb7022bc95f7e5f41ac78d0860303c8010080c2d72f0000e7670f32038107a59a2b9cfefae36ea21f5aa63c00', 'edskRkdTqB1GNzBtwnCUA4KX6gfS8oRWCuKdLZmYzgrRgGbwqswtbZeY59q5DxfNZahgV1B6V8eyZ79FpU4687cR9Qve6kXRWc', '03')
```

I get:

```
edsig: edsigtp9QDGUh8866M5LgRgRZjyF7WvLQtXjjVP6X3x1dYgvxVye9ybvFSaSNG5aJv9FjH9Es9d3nV2xUptmnENwWp6nJ4zmMZ6
```

Am I missing something?

My local test account is:

```
{
  "mnemonic": [
    "exercise",
    "situate",
    "gallery",
    "random",
    "fragile",
    "purpose",
    "elevator",
    "odor",
    "friend",
    "cage",
    "occur",
    "aim",
    "attract",
    "horror",
    "stool"
  ],
  "secret": "983142fbeba332140dbb4a8d4d5749c279ae2587",
  "amount": "23892354330",
  "pkh": "tz1ipQzB7tXwafCZn9hJBsJLqrAHWKjK6FNd",
  "password": "oBKWAWiGgE",
  "email": "rzqhubtg.lixdjury@tezos.example.org"
}
```

Comment: The two signatures you've added in the question are the same as far as I can see, so I have a hard time understanding what problem you're having. Also, it seems like the arguments you're giving to `eztz.crypto.sign` are not the same as the ones you're giving to `tezos-client`.

Comment: Thanks @arvidj I had pasted the incorrect signature

Comment: Check out the 3 wallet functions in the go-tezos library. See if that helps with the verification/confusion. https://github.com/goat-systems/go-tezos/blob/master/account/account.go#L123

Comment: @arvidj according to [rpc-signing-operations](http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/21/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-signing-operations/) the 0x is specifying it is hex, and the 03 prefix is the tezos watermark. The eztz function takes in a watermark parameter

Comment: @utdrmac thanks for the links, will check it out, but at a glance, not sure what the account has to do with sign/verify?

Comment: For comparison, you might try the sign function in https://github.com/murbard/pytezos and see if you get the same result as in tezos-client or eztz.

Comment: @MarkRobson If you look at the Go code I linked, all of the 3 wallet functions deal with signing and verifying addresses using crypto functions. You should be able to get an idea of what you are missing from your JS code. Disclaimer: I wrote all of those 3 wallet functions in the go library by reading the eztz library, so there's something you're missing.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input. I think I found the reason, in the comments on the page I was using for reference: http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/21/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-signing-operations/#respond as my code results in the same signature as eztc I think this is closed. Great community!

Comment: @MarkRobson, nice! Would you mind adding what you found out as an answer?

Comment: sure @arvidj my code is [here](https://github.com/roppa/tezmania/blob/4d3fa88fdab6676566a19eb2a498c8020c62f318/src/crypto/crypto.ts#L84). Pretty much stolen from eztz repo as I am just using this library to learn. It looks like it was working fine, just the steps I was following from a tutorial had a missing step. Wasted a couple of hours :-(